# Extraer un texto de un data frame

Tags: r, regex

Estoy intentando extraer de la col1 el texto que aparece en la col2

```
datos <- read.table(text = '
Id  col1    col2
1   "CCCCC2021429_Y999999G" Y999999G
2   "2382464_carlos pepe pepe"    2382464
3   "SUUBBaa202132377_1234567X" 1234567X
4   "04010110 FAAP CASAL 2019-2020" 04010110
5   "HHHHC202222229 H8256016G"  H8256016G
6   "SUECO202132429 9051016"    9051016
7   "CARMEN202132429 9066016Q"  9066016Q
8   "262979 asdd pepe pepe" 262979
9   "2382464P_rrfff pepe pepe"  2382464P
10  "h382464P marta peperez qqq"    h382464P
11  "kD_Y7865SSSS65H pepe"  Y7865SSSS65H
12  "HWD Q12345Z pepe"  Q12345Z
13  "pWHswD X7ERTY65T_pepe" X7ERTY65T
14  "AAA 7865SSSS65_pepe"   7865SSSS65
15  "aaa 9876H ana" 9876H
16  "xsw 7865SSSS65 pepe"   7865SSSS65', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Datos:**

```
Id  col1                             col2
1   CCCCC2021429_Y999999G            Y999999G
2   2382464_carlos pepe pepe         2382464
3   SUUBBaa202132377_1234567X        1234567X
4   04010110 FAAP CASAL 2019-2020    04010110
5   HHHHC202222229 H8256016G         H8256016G
6   SUECO202132429 9051016           9051016
7   CARMEN202132429 9066016Q         9066016Q
8   262979 asdd pepe pepe            262979
9   2382464P_rrfff pepe pepe         2382464P
10  h382464P marta peperez qqq       h382464P
11  kD_Y7865SSSS65H pepe             Y7865SSSS65H
12  HWD Q12345Z pepe                 Q12345Z
13  pWHswD X7ERTY65T_pepe            X7ERTY65T
14  AAA 7865SSSS65_pepe              7865SSSS65
15  aaa 9876H ana                    9876H
16  xsw 7865SSSS65 pepe              7865SSSS65
```

Es decir, me dan unicamente la col1 y tengo que obtener lo que viene en la col2.

En varios pasos he ido probando cosas, como borrar todo lo hay antes de "_"

```
datos$col3 = gsub( "^([^_]+_)", "", datos$col1 )
```

Borrar todo lo que hay detrás de un espacio en blanco etc.
Luego unir todas las columnas en una sola, pero siempre hay alguno que no sale o se sobrescribe uno q estaba bien por otro que esta mal.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido sacarlo.
No se me da bien los regex, a veces quería sacar una cosa y me salia otra, por ejemplo, quería sacar solo letra-digitos-letra y me sacaba también lo que no empieza por letra, aunque esto también me valía.

La idea es sacar cada clave en una columna y luego unirlas todas.

**Saco cada código en una columna:**
(Bastante mejorable)

```
datos$col3 <- datos$col1
datos$col3 <- sub("\\_", " ", datos$col3) 
datos$col4 <- str_extract(datos$col3, "\\w{1}\\d{4,}\\w{1}$") 
datos$col5 <- str_extract(datos$col3, "^\\d{4,}\\s") 
datos$col6 <- str_extract(datos$col3, "^\\d{3,}[A-z]")
datos$col7 <- str_extract(datos$col3, "[A-z]\\d{5,}[A-z]")
datos$col8 <- str_extract(datos$col3, "\\s[0-9].+\\s") 
datos$col9 <- str_extract(datos$col3, "\\s.+\\s")
```

**Uno las columnas:**

```
library(sqldf)

datos <- sqldf("select *, coalesce(col4, col5, col6, col7 ,col8,col9) unir from 'datos'")
```

**Borro columnas que me sobran:**

datos <- datos[ , -c(4:10)]

**Quito espacios en blanco:**

datos$unir <- gsub("\s", "", datos$unir)